# Sockets java - Beginner

Tags: java, sockets

I'm starting in java and have a problem with sockets, I wanted my server Meet and greet a value and then wanted to turn it into a `String`, to then include in a condition`if`. However, despite the server approved the text without problem, I can not pass the value for a `String`.

```java
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package javasockets;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class JavaSockets {

    public static String T = "s";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            ServerSocket sckServer = new ServerSocket(5000);

            System.out.println("Porta 5000 aberta!");
            Socket sck;

            while (true) {

                sck = sckServer.accept();
                try (Scanner entrada = new Scanner(sck.getInputStream())) {

                    while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {

                        System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());
                    }
                    String texto = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("ola" + texto);
                    String fnames = texto;
                    System.out.println("ola" + fnames);
                    System.out.println(texto);
                    if (texto.equals(T)) {
                        System.out.println("LOOL");
                    }
                }
                sckServer.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Cliente code, send messages to the socket 127.0.0.1", 5000

```java
package javasockets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            System.out.println("O cliente se conectou ao servidor!");

            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintStream saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

            while (teclado.hasNextLine()) {
                saida.println(teclado.nextLine());
            }
            saida.flush();
            saida.close();
            teclado.close();
        }

    }

    static Object getInetAddress() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

thanks for the  help

Answer (score 1):

Every call to nextLine () method, the server waits to receive a new string, but in the implementation of your client will only send a single string.

So try:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class JavaSockets {

    public static String T = "s";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            ServerSocket sckServer = new ServerSocket(5000);

            System.out.println("Porta 5000 aberta!");
            Socket sck;

            while (true) {

                sck = sckServer.accept();
                try (Scanner entrada = new Scanner(sck.getInputStream())) {

                    while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {

                        String texto = entrada.nextLine();

                        System.out.println(texto);
                        System.out.println("ola" + texto);

                        String fnames = texto;

                        System.out.println("ola" + fnames);
                        System.out.println(texto);
                        if (texto.equals(T)) {
                            System.out.println("LOOL");
                        }
                    }

                }
                sckServer.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This already working !! Was closing the while loop in the wrong place